# kableextra header across multiple rows for pdf output

Tags: r, latex, quarto, kableextra, gt

I have the following table that I try to reproduce. This [example](https://posit.co/wp-content/themes/Posit/public/markdown-blogs/columns-in-gt-0-9-0/index.html#an-improved-cols_label-function) from `gt` does exactly what I need, but I did only work in HTML and not PDF.)

[image]

My approach using `add_header_above` from `kableExtra` (any other package is also welcome):

[image]

My biggest problem is to take into account the `header_above` for column 2 and 3, while also getting column 1 and 4 in one header without the cline (valign: middle). I also want those two headers (1&4) to be vertically middle aligned and a linebreak after between in column 4 (without a white line as seperator).

**MWE using Quarto**

````markdown
---
title: "Example Table"
format:
  pdf:
    pdf-engine: xelatex
    mainfont: "Barlow"
    include-in-header: 
      text: |
        \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.35mm}
        \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8} 
        \arrayrulecolor{white}
---
```{r}
library(kableExtra)

df <- data.frame(
  age = 1:3,
  table1 = 1:3 / 10,
  table2 = 1:3 / 100
)

df$diff <- df$table1 - df$table2

colhd <- "#548235"
colbd <- "#FFF2CC"

kable(df, format = "latex",
      col.names = c("Age", "Table 1", "Table 2",
                    "Difference between Table 1 and Table 2")) |> 
  add_header_above(header = c(" " = 1, "Table Number" = 2, " " = 1),
                    background = colhd, color = "white") |> 
  row_spec(0, background = colhd, color = "white") |> 

  row_spec(1:3, background = colbd, color = "black") |>
  column_spec(1, background = colhd, color = "white")
```
````

Comment: Is kableextra a requirement?

Comment: No, any solution/hints are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for the PDF case: Trickier.**
Maybe you want to have a look at `flextable`? I find the package to be very versatile and straightforward.

I've taken your example and produced the table that you are looking for. Except for fonts you might want to adapt and choose, everything is there. You can copy-paste-run it directly and see the results.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  age = 1:3,
  table1 = 1:3 / 10,
  table2 = 1:3 / 100
)

df$diff <- df$table1 - df$table2
names(df) <- c("Age", "Table 1", "Table 2", " ")

colhd <- "#548235"
colbd <- "#FFF2CC"
std_border <- officer::fp_border(color = "white")
std_border_2 <- officer::fp_border(color = colhd, style = "none")

df_flex <- df %>%
  flextable::flextable() %>%
  flextable::border_remove() %>%
  flextable::add_header_row(
    values = c(
      "", "Table Number", "",
      "Difference between\ntable1 and table2"
    )
  ) %>%
  flextable::bg(bg = colbd, part = "body") %>%
  flextable::bg(bg = colhd, part = "header") %>%
  flextable::align(align = "center", part = "header") %>%
  flextable::merge_at(i = 1, j = c(2, 3), part = "header") %>%
  flextable::merge_at(i = 1:2, j = 4, part = "header") %>%
  flextable::color(color = "white", part = "header") %>%
  flextable::bg(j = 1, bg = colhd, part = "body") %>%
  flextable::color(j = 1, color = "white", part = "body") %>%
  flextable::width(width = c(1, 1, 1, 2)) %>%
  flextable::hline(i = 1, j = 2:3, border = std_border, part = "header") %>%
  flextable::hline(i = 1, j = c(1, 4), border = std_border_2, part = "header") %>%
  flextable::hline(i = 2, j = 1:3, border = std_border, part = "header") %>%
  flextable::hline(border = std_border, part = "body")  %>%
  flextable::vline(j = 1:3, border = std_border, part = "all")

df_flex
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This works perfectly in HTML output, however when I render it to pdf it looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/elhKMrI. And unfortunately, I need a PDF working solution.

Comment: You are right. In that case let me make some edits to the above... You will be able to produce the result. One thing: do not open the result in the viewer, but in Acrobat directly or in PDF Architect. The reason is that the Viewer displays the result with some missleading cell lines.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, it is almost what I need. There is still a white line between "between table1" :( I am not familiar with flextable, is that possible to eradicate that, maybe by using the same background color for that line?

Comment: Are you opening it in Adobe, PDF Architect or other? I tested that on Windows and it worked. On my Linux box when I open it with the Document Viewer, I see what you see. But if I open it with Okular, for instance, the line is gone...

Comment: I even printed it and the white line unfortunatly is still there, it is probably related to some latex pacakge.

Comment: Definitely a bug, then. You could ask the package creators for help, they are quite responsive. https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable